# Swiping in Coco2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to get the swiping to work for Cocos2d latest version here is my code:

```
-(void) setupGestureRecognizers 
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];

    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

    [swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];


}
```

It does not detect the swipe at all!

UPDATE 1:

I updated the code to the following and still no swipes are detected.

```
-(void) setupGestureRecognizers 
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];

    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

    [swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];


}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've tried to make this work as well but I've found an easier and also better to control method.

so for example if you wanted to detect a swipe to the left I'd so following.

Declare two variables in the interface of you're class

```
CGPoint firstTouch;
CGPoint lastTouch;
```

In the init method of the implementation of your class enable touches

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

3.Add these methods to your class

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //Swipe Detection Part 1
    firstTouch = location;
}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //Swipe Detection Part 2
    lastTouch = location;

    //Minimum length of the swipe
    float swipeLength = ccpDistance(firstTouch, lastTouch);

    //Check if the swipe is a left swipe and long enough
    if (firstTouch.x > lastTouch.x && swipeLength > 60) {
        [self doStuff];
    }

}
```

the method "doStuff" is whats called if a left swipe has occurred.

Comment: I prefer to use the UIGestureRecognizer since it is easy to create different kind of touch events.

Answer (score 3):

The code is correct and should work.

You might want to verify that neither userInteraction nor touch input are disabled on the gl view or the main window.

You should also check if cocos2d is eating the touches somehow. The EAGLView class is the first receiver of the touches, and forwards them to the CCTouchDispatcher. I can imagine that if you have targeted touch delegates they may "swallow" the touches. Although cocos2d should receive the touches only after the gesture recognizers.

Comment: I updated the code in my original question but still the swipes are not detected.